# Software for Windows/Office Asset Management

Tags: windows, digital-asset-management, asset-management

I'm searching for a Windows/Office asset management software, preferably one that can detect products installed on the computers AND manually added licenses (we have some XP licenses which aren't installed anywhere, but would like to record). Do you know any software that can do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer.
It detects the license keys for Microsoft Windows and Office on network computers.
You can create reports on these keys and store manually added keys in the program’s [License Manager](http://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/help/license-manager.shtml).

The program can check whether the added keys are used on the network or not.